# Verify Login before sending json to webservice from excel VBA

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, excel, authentication

I am working on an excel macro that enable user to select certain rows,and then sends it to a web service in JSON format. But before that I need to make sure identity of user. For that I am planning to use the login credentials of my main web application. When the user clicks on export data from excel, he is taken to login page of web application via internet explorer.
I want to allow the user to export data if he log in successfully. 
But I am not able to figure out how to detect from vba script, that user has logged in successfully. I have settled in for this method as I don't want to send username/password from vba directly. Is there a way to detect a successful log in from excel vba code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot think of any VBA only solution. A possible and not very elegant way to do this could be letting the VBA check the page for some html elements (getElementById) that are available only if the user is logged in.